# Plotly-Dash: How to print hoverData of a bar plot?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a Bar plot in my Dash application. I want to print the hover data whenever I hover over a particular bar.

I have tried hoverData property of go.Bar() in my callback.

```
data = go.Bar(x=dict.keys(), y=dict.values(), name=ver, text=dict.values(), textposition='auto')

layout = go.Layout(barmode='group', hovermode='closest')

html.Div([dcc.Graph(id='main_graph', figure={'data': data, 'layout': layout}
)], style={'width':'70%', 'float':'left'})

html.Div([html.Pre(id='hover')], style={'width':'30%', 'float':'right'})

@app.callback(Output('hover', 'children'), [Input('main_graph', 'hoverData')])
def disp_hover_data(hover_data):
    print(hover_data)
```

Expected result: The hover data of hovered bar

Actual result: None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **return** the `hover_data` object instead of **printing** it.

```
@app.callback(Output('hover', 'children'), [Input('main_graph', 'hoverData')])
def disp_hover_data(hover_data):
    return hover_data
```

Right now, if you check your "server" log, i.e. the terminal where it is running, you will see the hover_data printed there. If you fix it, it should show up in `hover`.